# Graph databases vs hierarchical databases

Tags: database, hierarchical

Putting up an open ended question here...

what is the core difference between the graph databases (e.g. neo4j) and hierarchical databases (e.g. IMS in mainframe world) ?

Are they same / comparable ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Off-topic because this is much too broad, opinion-based, open-ended and asking for recommendations (see the [FAQ] and [Ask]).  You could write a book on the subject.  I suggest you do a lot more research and if you have specific questions, ask on [dba.se]